# how to sort list in python which has two numbers per index value?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

**My code**

`b=[((1,1)),((1,2)),((2,1)),((2,2)),((1,3))] 
for i in range(len(b)): 
    print b[i]`

**Obtained output:**
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(1, 3)

**how do i sort this list by the first element or/and second element in each index value to get the output as:**
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)

**OR**

(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(1, 3)

It would be nice if both columns are sorted as shown in the desired output, how ever if either of the output columns is sorted it will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `b = sorted(b, key = lambda i: (i[0], i[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

The `sorted` builtin does this.

```
>>> sorted (b)
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

This only sorts by the first element, to sort on the second

```
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda i: i[1])
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Also notice that Python doesn't allow this nested tuple; the paren inside a paren is reduced to just one.

```
>>> b=[((1,1)),((1,2)),((2,1)),((2,2)),((1,3))]
>>> b
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]
```